# Is there a name for the deliberate use of incorrect grammar?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, terminology

Is there a name for the deliberate use of incorrect grammar?

I'm thinking of the phrase "As sure as eggs is eggs", which I heard used by a well-educated speaker recently. Of course, they were aware that grammatically the plural *eggs* requires the verb form *are*, but I wondered whether there is a name for the intentional use of so-called 'bad grammar'. Another example is the deliberate use of "ain't" by British English speakers.

Comment: They are figures of speech - perhaps forms of irony. I am doubtful, however, if you will find a named category specific to what you require. But take a look at "mimesis" - from "mimicry". I'm not going to pay for the repair - because it wasn't me **wot done it**" - sort of mimics a suspected criminal speaking to the police, or someone in authority.

Comment: Dialog for characters can be intentionally "ungrammatical" aiming for realistic speech, trying to reproduce what you might hear spoken. (I get a kick out of altered spellings like "sez" that do nothing.)

Comment: We can be deliberately ungrammatical for effect— to be folksy, humorous, emphatic, etc. as in your example when a person who knows better (and who knows you know) uses ain't. This extends to effects such as sensational spelling and exaggerated pronunciation like Tony the Tigers cereal catchphrase They’re grrrrrreat! and Our computer is so sloooow.

Comment: We might ungrammatical for convenience, e.g. you "paint yourself in a grammatical corner" while speaking and get out of it with something ungrammatical or perhaps borderline grammatical, such as an extended "group genitive" like "Listen to this! The funny old man I told you about yesterday when we were having coffee 's son is none other than...." (said perhaps with a smile or some eye-rolling and hand gestures as a "sorry, I know, but I'm not going to start over").

Comment: *Ain't* isn't bad grammar unless used in a place where the words it abbreviates don't fit.

Comment: I and I think others avoid "I ain't" except for effect.

Comment: @ nnnnnn Many – hopefully, most – would disagree.

Comment: I'm not sure [***English as She Is Spoke***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_as_She_Is_Spoke) falls into this category, but ***We Don't Need No Education*** surely qualifies ([***as any fule kno***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Any_fule_kno), if we allow orthographic versions! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Or in response to someone's error - grammatical or otherwise - "Where were you edificated?", or "Where were you drug up?"

Comment: @nnnnnn That might have been true 200 years ago.

Comment: @WS2: That's *Where **was** you drug up?* to us facetiously uneducated Southerners! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Or the response to the news of magistrates sending a light-fingered to the cells - "That'll learn him".

Comment: @GArthurBrown - It's still the case. The word is pretty much universally considered inappropriate in formal English, but that's not a matter of grammar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in [@Edwin's comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/574238/is-there-a-name-for-the-deliberate-use-of-incorrect-grammar?noredirect=1#comment1431136_574239) referring to [this earlier Answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/298810/2637), the relevant term here is...

> [**Enallage**](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-enallage-1690647)
> *...related to **solecism** (a deviation from conventional word order). **Enallage**, however, is usually regarded as a **deliberate stylistic device**, whereas a **solecism** is commonly treated as an **error of usage***.

---

A few famous examples from advertising / TV / movies...

> *Got milk?*
> *Eat fresh*
> *We was robbed*
> *Mistah Kurtz—he dead*
> *Thunderbirds are go*

"All of these stick in our minds because they’re just wrong—wrong enough to be right" (Mark Forsyth, *Rhetorical Reasons That Slogans Stick*, The New York Times, November 13, 2014)

Comment: I think you have found the answer here. One of the definitions in the link you included was "enallage: a slight deliberate grammatical mistake that makes a sentence stand out." I think that is a great description of what I was asking.

Comment: Well, ***I*** didn't find it! As acknowledged in the first line of my answer, @Edwin found it for me! But coming back to this now, it seems I got my links messed up in the Answer, so I suppose I'd better sign off this comment and do some further investigation...

Comment: Some of them are deliberately chosen to sound like a particular vernacular. "Mistah Kurtz—he dead" sounds like southern plantation slave dialect, "We was robbed" sounds Brooklynese.

Comment: @Barmar: I just copied that one verbatim, but personally I think of it as *We **wuz** robbed* - the familiar lament of Sarf London football supporters of the losing team. While trying to establish some kind of "origin" for the usage just now, I came across the new-to-me but truly "immortal words" [*They should of stood in bed*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/should-have-stood-in-bed--i) (said of some baseball player who got off his sickbed to play, but performed badly). Sometimes the "non-standard grammar" is only there to be "striking / quirky / amusing".

Comment: "We wuz" seems to be common to several lower-class vernaculars in both America and the UK.

Comment: @Barmar: The earliest *we **wuz** robbed* I found in Google Books was 1896 *Secondary Education - Volume 14, National Education Association of the **United States***. But I found *we **was** robbed* from Knapp & Baldwin's 1828 *The Newgate Calendar* (quirky / grisly trivia about Newgate Prison in ***London***). So I think Brits got there first! :)

Comment: Funnily, I first read it [un-u-'laazh], as if it were from the French. Thanks to the ThoughtCo.com link in the answer, I discovered it comes from the Greek and is pronounced much like 'analogy'. (Sorry but I don't do IPA, neither the writing nor the beer).
The word also exists in Spanish (why wouldn't it?) but I didn't know it. And it sounds pretty different from the Spanish 'analogy'.

Answer (score 2):

"Solecism" is the closest thing that comes to mind. And "Malapropism" is the mistaken use of an incorrect word in place of a word with a similar sound.

Comment: But as I understand it they are both errors as opposed to deliberate strategies for effect - which is what the OP seemed to be asking.

Comment: Hello, Mahny. These terms don't fit exactly (the _deliberate_ use) and have been given more appropriately as answers elsewhere on ELU.

Comment: There is a large specialized vocabulary for figures of speech. A good repository and explanation of them is at [Silva Rhetoricae](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/S/solecism.htm) which is fun to explore.  @EdwinAshworth, there is no distinguishing netween deliberate and unconscious in these historical terms. It's a solecism whether you meant it or not.

Comment: An alternate term,[which is frequently suggested here on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=catachresis) is [catachresis](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/C/catachresis.htm)

Comment: @Mitch Yes, but that hypernymic answer has appeared before. As has the correct, precisionist answer: _enallage_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Just adding more information to help those who come along. I don't want to shut down pathways - the question linked to as duplicate isn't the actual duplicate.